# Avoiding PWA to reload when using Web Share Target API

Tags: javascript, web, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, web-share

I'm working on a PWA that plays music.
It accepts shared URLs from other android apps via [Web Share Target](https://web.dev/web-share-target/) API.

**The problem :**
Whenever something is shared via the API (*which uses GET request*)I my PWA is reloded (as expected).
And the already playing Music stops because of that.

**Is there any way that page doesn't reload ?**

Currently fetching shared params with this code.

```
const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location);
```

[My PWA](https://krokxtream.herokuapp.com) is a Single Page application

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

One way to prevent reloading is by setting up a fake path in your Web Application Manifest that solely serves for the purpose of receiving shares (note that this uses HTTP POST and "multipart/form-data" encoding [so later you can extend the app to receive entire files]):

```json
{
    "share_target": {
        "action": "/receive-shares",
        "method": "POST",
        "enctype": "multipart/form-data",
        "params": {
            "title": "name",
            "text": "description",
            "url": "link"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your service worker's fetch handler, you deal with the incoming shares and redirect the user to the home:

```js
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
  if ((e.request.url.endsWith('/receive-shares')) &&
      (e.request.method === 'POST')) {
    return e.respondWith((async () => {
      // This function is async.
      const formData = await fetchEvent.request.formData();
      // Do something with the URL…
      const url = formData.get('url');
      // Store the URL, process it, communicate it to the clients…
      // You need to redirect the user somewhere, since the path
      // /receive-shares does not actually exist.
      return Response.redirect('/', 303);
    })())
  }
  /* Your regular fetch handler */
})
```